Displaying Timestamp and Username in Message Prompt in Go TCP Chat Application - go
I’m working on a TCP chat application in Go where the server allows multiple clients to connect and communicate. I’ve hit a snag with a particular feature and could use some help.
Requirement: I need to display a message prompt in the format [timestamp][username] at the cursor’s position while the user is typing their message or waiting to receive a message.
Issue: Despite implementing the code below, the timestamp and username do not appear at the cursor’s position when running the program.
Code Snippet:
func (c *Client) sendMessages(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        displayPromptWithTimestampAndUsername(c.name)

        msg := utils.ReadInput("")

        if strings.TrimSpace(msg) != "" {
            utils.SendMessage(c.conn, msg)
        }
    }
}

func displayPromptWithTimestampAndUsername(username string) {
    currentTime := time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
    fmt.Printf("\r[%s][%s]: ", currentTime, username)
}

Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to ensure the timestamp and username are displayed correctly at the cursor’s position?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I’ve verified that the displayPromptWithTimestampAndUsername function is being called, but the output isn’t reflected at the cursor’s position as expected

If I understand correclty, your issue isn't related to TCP at all. You are just in need for an interactive shell library, like https://github.com/charmbracelet/bubbletea.

It depends on your utils.ReadInput function, since it might change your stdout output.
The following sample code worked for me , For utils.ReadInput function
func ReadInput(text string) string {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print(text)
    text, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
    return text
}

